# Chrome extension and content scripts can communicate only in "inspect popup" mode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I have this rather simple extention and content script:

**manifest.json:**

```
{
  "name": "My.First.App.Uses.Native.Api",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "My app uses my first Native Api",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon-128__2.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "nativeMessaging", "activeTab"
  ],
  "browser_action": {"default_popup": "ext-page.htm"},
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["file:///*"],
      "js": ["content-script.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**ext-script.js:**

```
// Listen for messages that come from the client script.
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function( request, sender, sendResponse ) {
    if( request.greeting ) {
        //connectToNative();
        sendResponse( { farewell: request.greeting + ' -> received' } );
    }
  } );
```

**content-script.js:**

```
var btn = document.getElementById( 'mybutton' );
if( btn ) {
    btn.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
        var msg = document.getElementById( 'mytext' ).value;
        if( msg ) {
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage( { greeting: msg }, function( response ) {
                console.log( response.farewell );
            } );
            //port.postMessage({joke: "Knock knock"});
        }
        else {
            alert( "content script could not send message" );
        }
    } );
}
```

**ext-page.htm:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src='./ext-script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    This is a test Extention.
</body>
</html>
```

**A sample page which the content script is injected in :**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Connecting to a Chrome Extention using Content Script</title>
</head>

<body>
    <p>
        <!--<input id="btn" type="button" value="open document" />-->
        <input id="mytext" type="text" />
        <input id="mybutton" name="mybutton" type="button" value="open document" />
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

**My problem:**
If I select the extention and "inspect popup" it (meaning start the debug mode), and click *mybutton* button on my sample page, then I receive a message back from  the extension and I can see it in my page's console. What I want is to get that message simply right after clicking that button in my sample page-- of course **without** debugging the extension. If I do not "inspect popup" the extension, then I receive this error message:

***Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'farewell' of undefined***

Thanks!

Comment: [`chrome.extension.sendRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-sendRequest) and [`chrome.extension.onRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#event-onRequest) were deprecated already and use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` and `chrome.runtime.onMessage` instead.

Comment: I have changed those, but still the same error message. I suppose it should not raise errors (at least for a while) even if some methods are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I think because you're executing your alert inside main.js which is inside your popup, the popup needs to be open.  Try inserting your alert inside background.js.  Because background.js gets inserted into your sample page as a content_script, the alert should show up right in  your sample page.

Instead of in background.js

```
    if( msg ) {
        chrome.extension.sendRequest( msg );
    }
```

Do

```
var msg = document.getElementById( 'mytext' ).value;
    if( msg ) {
        alert( msg );
    }
```

The docs suggest to have a manifest like this:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test",
    "version": "0.1",
    "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    //this script is the main one which your extension communicates with
    "persistent": false
},
"browser_action": {
    "default_title": "BET",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
    //this html file is the one that will be shown when clicked on your extension icon
},
"content_scripts": [{
    //this file will get injected into the tabs
    "matches": ["file:///*"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
}],
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"
]
```

}

So inside your content.js your should have

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
    console.log(response.farewell);
});
```

And inside background.js you receive the message

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(request.greeting);
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
        sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
});
```

Doing it this way, you will be able to log what you sent from your injected script to your extension...just open the background console from the extensions page.

Hope this will help if you change the structure around a little.  Let me know if it helps

Comment: Then what is the point of that? What I have written here is supposed to connect an extension (which its code resides in main.js) to my content script (resides in background.js). If I wanted to simply call something in my content script (background.js), then what would be the point of  "my question"?

Comment: Actually what I am trying to do is to send a message by content script and catch it there in the extension and show it. Maybe I should use another technique, but this is what I am aiming.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're aiming to do something else.  I'm no expert but from my experience the extension has a background script which the content script communicates with.  Your script naming convention is different then the docs suggest but anyway...I'll update my answer with a suggestion from [this](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)

Comment: I shall give it a try, but I suggest you remove that first part (up to the manifest) that we agreed is not related to the question otherwise in the first sight this does not sound a suitable answer.

Comment: Technically, in your question you wanted to get the alert to pop up right away after getting clicked.  The first part of the question will make it pop up right away.

Comment: @RezaAhmadi You may want to go through the [architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).  Content and background scripts are two different things which you seem to be conflating.  denikov is correct that your problem is that the popup only exists while it's open, and that a background script seems to be more appropriate (but it's hard to tell without knowing what you're aiming to actually do).